# Android, how to not destroy the activity when I rotate the device?

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

I have an app that works only in portrait mode, and I have made the changes in my manifest file for every activity the orientation to be portrait. But when I rotate the device, the activity recreates again.
How to not destroy the activity?

Comment: This is often advised against, you could try setting your applications orientation programatically with something like:

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: Why would it be against? Let's say we have a service that takes 2 seconds to run. If the activity destroys every time, that service keeps running every time while I just need it to run once.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

For **API 12 and below**: add

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Add "screenSize" if you are targeting **API 13 or above** because whenever your orientation changes so does your screen size, otherwise new devices will continue to destroy your activity. See Egg's answer below for more information on using "screenSize"

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

to your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml. This way your Activity wont be restarted automatically. See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) for more infos

Comment: The activity is restarted again.

I don't know what's the point of doing all the stuff that has to be done when the activity rotates, even if it is not rotating virtually. Is there a way to disable that messages that the sensor sends to the OS about the rotation, or something like that, to fix this problem from its root?

Comment: on what device are you programming? remember, that for example sliding out the keyboard could also restart your activity... (if that's the reason set confChanges to "keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation")

Comment: This disables the layout change. How do I fix that?

Comment: This solution resolves the destroy and creating activity but, how to handle layout changes. I mean to say when the change the orientation, loading corresponding layout.

Comment: Is there a way to set the android:configChanges parameter programmatically, as opposed to in the manifest file?

Answer (score 109):

From the official document flurin said,

> Note: If your application targets API level 13 or higher (as declared
>   by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), then you should
>   also declare the "screenSize" configuration, because it also changes
>   when a device switches between portrait and landscape orientations.

So if your app targets API level 13 or higher, you should set this config instead:

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: Thank you so much! All the other answers miss this the part where API level 13 introduces this screenSize thingy.
You just saved my life! :)

Comment: Great tip it's hard to keep up with the documentation when you do it part time.

Comment: +1 Nice touch man. Thank you for sharing this solution for us. You saved my day. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 9):

The right solution is

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Android documentation:

> The current available screen size has changed. This represents a change in the currently available size, relative to the current aspect ratio, so will change when the user switches between landscape and portrait. However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).*

Answer (score 6):

I was messing this up for a little bit and then relized that inside the Manifest file I was putting the configChanges on the Application level and not on the Activity Level. Here is what the code looks like when it is correctly working for me.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
</application>
```

Comment: You should share code within your post instead of an image.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual manifest code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Now that Android supports split screen ("multi-window" in Android parlance), you'll probably want to add screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation as well. So to handle rotation and split screen you'll want something like this in android:configChanges

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code in Floating Image. It has the most interesting way of handling screen rotation ever. http://code.google.com/p/floatingimage/source/browse/#svn/trunk/floatingimage/src/dk/nindroid/rss/orientation

Answer (score -1):

write in manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

and override this in activity that solved your problem:

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: Why would overriding the onConfigurationChanged method and calling the original implementation doing anything useful?