# Sideview restarts Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation

On an android App I made, whenever the user turns the app to the side, the app turns sideways and restarts (this was on the droid). I don't want to this to happen. I want the app to not restart when the device is turned sideways.

Also I would prefer the app to be locked in the vertical position.

How would I go about this two thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been covered numerous times [Android, how to not destroy the activity when I rotate the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329318/android-how-to-not-destroy-the-activity-when-i-rotate-the-device)