# Change screen orientation in Android without reloading the activity

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I want to change the orientation programmatically while running my Android App, with these lines of code:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

They work so far, but the main problem is that the whole activity is reloaded when the screen orientation changes, and I don't want that. Is it possible? Thanks.

**EDIT: OK, after I while I found out what I was missing. I had to include also "screenSize" in the configChanges property, so having**

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

**solved the whole thing.**

Comment: I think you should check out the third choice in this answer.  I believe that is how PhoneGap handles orientation changes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913130/dont-reload-application-when-orientation-changes

Comment: You can rotate your activity/fragment view Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23494104/8696548

Answer (score 29):

See the edit by @luisfer. For targeting Android 3.2 and above, you need BOTH

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Comment: This changed all my problems with, the navigation stack too. thanks man

Answer (score 4):

You need to override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and write the application state values you want to change to the Bundle parameter

Comment: +1, this is the correct answer => what he has asked is not posible, just with this solution he can do what he want, only with API above 13 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidManifest file add `android:configChanges="orientation"` for the activity you want to handle this orientation

In activity use onConfigurationChange overrided method. Do task you want to handle in orientation change.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. Could it be maybe because I'm using Phonegap/HTML5 in the activity? Thank you.

Comment: @RajShah for what need more code? did you read the question? how about the title?

Answer (score 1):

Ansewered here:

[Android, how to not destroy the activity when I rotate the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329318/android-how-to-not-destroy-the-activity-when-i-rotate-the-device)

Add:

`android:configChanges="orientation"`

To your androidmanifest.

see:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. Could it be maybe because I'm using Phonegap/HTML5 in the activity? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Call this method And Set manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```