# Change Screen Orientation programmatically using a Button

Tags: android, android-button, screen-orientation

I think this is implementable since screen rotation behaviour can go up to the application level.

Comment: Have you tried this ? :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873755/change-screen-orientation-in-android-without-reloading-the-activity

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Yes it is implementable!

[ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

[ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

**ActivityInfo**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html

Refer the 
link:

```
Button buttonSetPortrait = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setPortrait);
Button buttonSetLandscape = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setLandscape);

buttonSetPortrait.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
   }

});

buttonSetLandscape.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
   }

});
```

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/08/set-screen-orientation-programmatically.html

Comment: Thanks. But is this function that needs to be run on a rooted device? It seems not working on my cell phone but on my rooted tablet.

Comment: No it's not like that.. Actually i tested the code in that link before posting.. It was working in my device..

Comment: okay, yea, you are right. i just tested another device and it works well. well, my Samsung Galaxy Nexus doesnt work. Dont know why.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this locking the application in that mode. When User is rotating the device the screen is not rotating.

Comment: If I set the orientation to landscape programatically as this answer, the user is not able anymore to change the orientation by rotating the device. Any way to handle this problem? I want to do what was taught in this answer but then when the user rotates the device it will keep changing the orientation.

Comment: @SoonSantos I achieved something like that by starting an async tasked, delayed by a couple of seconds.  Run myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(originalOrientation) in it. Of course this is ugly and comes with its own set of problems.

Comment: That last link is wrong, take this: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/08/set-screen-orientation-programmatically.html

Answer (score 46):

Yes, you can **set the screen orientation programatically** anytime you want using:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

for landscape and portrait mode respectively. The setRequestedOrientation() method **is available for the Activity class**, so it can be used inside your Activity.

And this is how you can **get the current screen orientation** and set it adequatly depending on its current state:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
final int orientation = display.getOrientation(); 
 // OR: orientation = getRequestedOrientation(); // inside an Activity

// set the screen orientation on button click
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {

              switch(orientation) {
                   case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
                       setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                       break;
                   case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                       setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                       break;                   
               }
          }
   });
```

Taken from here: http://techblogon.com/android-screen-orientation-change-rotation-example/

EDIT

Also, you can get the screen orientation using the `Configuration`:

```
Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `getRequestedOrientation()` to get the current screen orientation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21909327/1037294

Comment: `getRequestedOrientation()` gives you `UNSPECIFIED` when you start the app. So with the above listener it won't change screen and if you add `UNSPECIFIED` to the `switch` it should put the screen in one of **Portrait / Landscape** position first.

Answer (score 25):

Wherever possible, please don't use SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE or SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT. Instead use:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

These allow the user to orient the device to either landscape orientation, or either portrait orientation, respectively. If you've ever had to play a game with a charging cable being driven into your stomach, then you know exactly why having both orientations available is important to the user.

Note: For phones, at least several that I've checked, it only allows the "right side up" portrait mode, however, SENSOR_PORTRAIT works properly on tablets.

Note: this feature was introduced in API Level 9, so if you must support 8 or lower (not likely at this point), then instead use:

```
setRequestedOrientation(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9 ?
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE :
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9 ?
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT :
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 21):

Use this to set the orientation of the screen:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

and don't forget to add this to your manifest:

```
android:configChanges = "orientation"
```

Comment: You need both `"orientation|screenSize"` , Look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Answer (score 13):

A working code:

```
private void changeScreenOrientation() {
    int orientation = yourActivityName.this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        showMediaDescription();
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        hideMediaDescription();
    }
    if (Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
            }
        }, 4000);
    }
}
```

call this method in your button click

Answer (score 1):

Android-Kotlin:

to make rotate X:

```
binding.btnRotateHorizontal.setOnClickListener {
     requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE
}
```

to make rotate Y:

```
binding.btnRotateVertical.setOnClickListener {
     requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes ، [Hariharan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-a-button?answertab=oldest#tab-top) answer works fine . but you should add below line to AndroidManifest.xml in activity tag :

```
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

**if not add above line , Hariharan answer not work    .**

Thanks [Benny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-a-button/67758164#comment72617609_18269967) !

Answer (score 0):

mine worked with:

```
setLandscapeIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            setLandscapeIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setPortraitIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

setPortraitIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
                setLandscapeIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setPortraitIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

In Manifest

```
android:configChanges = "orientation|screenSize"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

NOTE: setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); was not working on my device