# Rotate the home screen programmatically

Tags: android

I tried rotating my android home screen on 2.3.6 but the homescreen doesn't rotate. I just wanted to know whether it is disabled by android operating system. if not, then why my home screen doesn't rotate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programatically-using-a-button

Comment: Might need a little more background, is this a physical device or a virtual one? There is often a setting that allows you to lock rotation on your device, I'm not sure about 2.3.6 specifically though. For me it's under settings>display>auto-rotate screen, but I am on 4.4.2 so it may be different.

Comment: You can't rotate the default home screen, if you are creating an Homescreen app yes you can. Just rotate your app.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno, sorry for the late reply. Thanks a lot for the help. Keep helping....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The determination of whether any app changes its look based upon orientation is up to the developers of the app. In your case, apparently the developers of the home screen app decided to lock the orientation to portrait. Google's home screen implementations historically have had this behavior, at least on phones.