# Landscape app and onConfigurationChanged never called

Tags: android, rotation, landscape, portrait

I need to handle device **rotation** in my app.
At the same time, I need to have the app in landscape mode.
If in the manifest file I've:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

the onConfigurationChanged method is never called.

How to handle this ?

```
@Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            // Checks the orientation of the screen
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

                viewRotate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewControl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

                viewControl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewRotate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }


        }
```

Comment: could you add to your post the activity mapping from your xml?

Comment: it is for in case you did not add the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html android:configChanges

Comment: already added android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" but nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

You've locked the orientation in landscape, of course the onConfigurationChanged dosen't get called. Also onConfigurationChanged dosen't get called when entering the activity.
Also you might want to see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18268304/3549142