# Handling orientation inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I have a `activity` in which I load a `fragment`. Lets say I have two sections inside `fragment layout`(section A and B) , but while I switch to landscape then I have to show only section A . How will i know the orientation change inside fragment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programatically-using-a-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override `onConfigurationChanged` to be notified when the orientation changed add code below in your fragment class:

```
@Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        //landscape
    }else{
        //portrait
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the orientation of the screen is changed the `Fragment` will be destroyed and created again, so `onDestroy()` and `onCreate()` are called. in your `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` (or wherever you need to) you can check for the current screen rotation with the following code:

```
int screenRotation = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        if(screenRotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || screenRotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            //LANDSCAPE
        } else {
            //PORTRAIT
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this functionality android provides Sliding pane layout [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html)

and watch this tutorials also official google developers tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jl3-lzlzOJI&t=1007s