# Android Screen rotation, ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION

Tags: android, accelerometer, screen-rotation

am trying to make my Android application rotate as soon as it run and fix the rotation, i have tried a wide range of method like : **Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION** it doesn't make it rotate, but it just enable the rotate feature, i need your help thank you in  advance (^_^). here is my code :

`

```
TableRow tableRow;
Time HourProgram;
RotateAnimation r;
int H = 12000, M = 1200;
int averageConsultationTime = 30;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.table);
    setAutoOrientationEnabled(this, true);

}

public static void setAutoOrientationEnabled(Context context,
        boolean enabled) {
    Log.i("OK", "setAutoOrientationEnabledOK");
    Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, enabled ? 1 : 0);
}

public static boolean getRotationScreenFromSettingsIsEnabled(Context context) {

    int result = 0;
    try {
        result = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION);
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result == 1;
}
```

`

Comment: give [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18268304/2900127) a try

Comment: Activities rotate by default in Android, so you should make sure *auto rotation* option is enabled in your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add this attribute to your activity in the AndroidManifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

You can find more information about Android activities attributes [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Answer (score 2):

add this code in `onCreate` in main Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
  }
```