# Rotate whole android layout

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

Is it possoble to rotate the whole android userinterface on an eventlistener ?
For example an app which runs in the background and after putting the headphones in the whole interface turn 180° until you put it out again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to change layout programmatically (Although not sure about 180 degrees?).

See this link: [Change Screen Orientation programmatically using a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-a-button)

The first answer he has explained how to change layout programmatically instead of setOnClickListner you can use your eventListener.

EDIT: Look at this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG

Its the broadcast which takes place in the event a headset was plugged in.