# Switch and automaticlly the screen orientation according the type of device phone or tablette

Tags: android

Is there any tips to detect and switch the screen orientation of the device, i'm using a webView to display my site and the solution of fixing it on manifest isn't good for me now 
ps: i'm starting on android dev thx guys ;D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check orientation on Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone)

Comment: This has been answered previously.
Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-a-button