# Is there a way to set programmatically the orientation to reverse portait?

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

1. Is there a way to set programmatically the orientation to reverse portrait?
2. Can I disable orientation change animation ?

Comment: [How to detect orientation change in layout in Android?](//stackoverflow.com/a/5726776)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes by using

you can change it with:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

to detect orientation change  implement an

```
 OrientationEventListener mOrientationListener;
```

you can find more help [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2262133&seqNum=4)

Or a better approach can be simply force a screen orientation in your AndroidManifest.xml file like this for example:

```
<activity android:name=".DisableScreenRotationAndroid" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Comment: Can I disable orientation change animation ?

Comment: Yes in your android manifest you can force it try something like   <activity android:name=".DisableScreenRotationAndroid" android:screenOrientation="landscape">

Answer (score 1):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Hope this helps

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE

If you need more Reference then 
[Change Screen Orientation programmatically using a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-a-button)

Comment: Can I disable orientation change animation ?