# android recyclerview adapter portrait only mode

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview adapter where i want to set it to portrait only.
I cant seem to find any resources on this.

Is there a way to do this programatically?

can i set it in onCreateViewHolder?

```
public class AlarmRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder> {


@Override
public AlarmRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                    int viewType) {

    AlarmRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = null;
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_alarms, parent, false);
    dataObjectHolder = new AlarmRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder(view);
    return dataObjectHolder;

}
```

Comment: set your activity containing the `recyclerview` as portrait in mabifest

Comment: I ended up setting the fragment that contains this as portrait. It works

Answer (score 1):

Specific views cannot request orientation. Activities  can request orientation.

You can achieve as needed by adding below code in manifest:

```
 <activity
  android:name=".YourActivityName"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: This view is not an activity. The manifest simply doesnt see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your activity's orientation in 2 ways:

1. Using manifest as @nice j suggested
2. Here is how you can set your activity's orientation programatically: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-a-button)

Hope it helps

Comment: this class doesnt extend activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

1. In Android Manifest File

   ```xml
   <activity
     android:name=".YourActivityName"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
   ```
2. Do it in Activity class programatically:

   ```java
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
   ```

Comment: This view is not an activity. The manifest simply doesnt see it.