# Preventing my Activity to change orientation depending on its content

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

In my app `MainActivity` contains a `BottomNavigation`, so it can display different tabs. Now my intention was, to force some of them to stay in portrait orientation, regardless of how the user holds the device.

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new OverviewFragment()).commit();
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_overview:
                        selectedFragment = new OverviewFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_reports:
                        selectedFragment = new ReportsFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_settings:
                        selectedFragment = new SettingsFragment();
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        };

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>
```

At least one tab should be displayable in portrait AND in landscape mode. Do I have to add some stuff into the xml, or do some java magic? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Screen Orientation programmatically using a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-a-button)

Comment: Can you show required UI, it's bit unclear what you are explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `screenOrientation` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity
    android:name="yourActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

This activity will remain portrait always.

If you need it programatically then you can use this.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

**Edit** If i understood right, you want make different layout for different orientation.

> Then create a **`layout-land`** directory and place the landscape layout XML
> file in that directory.

Comment: I already knew this, but the spiky stone is, that at least one of my tabs (which are fragments and they don't really have an orientation) should be able to be displayed in landscape.

Comment: This will come also, but first, my other tabs should stop rotating.

Comment: Can you show required output UI for landscape version.

Comment: not now i guess, there's still too much construction area, i will clean this up and create a second layout for landscape mode.

Comment: I am still unable to get your point of view. Let me know if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

To set Orientation, Just add `screenOrientation` inside your `manifest` in your `activity tag`

> to set orientation - portrait

```
  <activity
        android:name=".YourActivityNAME"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

> to set orientation - landscape

```
  <activity
        android:name=".YourActivityNAME"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

> Or you can do this Programmatically by using code below:-

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Use this line with that activity you want to use in portrait mode in `manifest.xml`

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

like this

```
<activity
            android:name=".app.comman.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your `activity` tag in `Menifest` file `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. like below,

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put these lines in Manifest so that the screen orientation would be **portrait**.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" />
```