# How do i check Rotate Your Device programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I want to load one url into my webview,  Its a Casino game. But when i open the app it show "Please Rotate Your Device" in a black screen.

How i can check that message programmatically and set the screen orientation landscape instead of user rotating their device ?

**My MainActivity Code :**

```
package com.mob.wunderin.oapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);


        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.myWebview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://deuceswildcards.site/wildcards.php?app=fun&Gtype=poker#/main");

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mob.wunderin.oapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**The Output :**

[Click here for Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bDTG.png)

**Please help me to check the "Rotate your device" message and set the screen orientation to landscape programatically ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Screen Orientation programmatically using a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-a-button)

Comment: Why do you even bother making an app?, this url works good in a mobile browser

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

to your Activity tag. It will force the device into landscape while that Activity is displayed, while allowing either landscape orientation (based on the device's sensor readings).

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

EDIT

Remove this line from your Activity as well:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
```

Comment: I just added these lines of codes into my activity tag. Its going to "landscape" on startup but after its back to Portrait mode.

Comment: As for your other comment, I'm guessing that as soon as the device goes back to portrait, that message will appear, no matter what. You need to the app to always be in landscape.

Comment: I have options to turn on ADS, when i turn on ads it should come in Portrait mode

Comment: Now it comes always landscape mode

Comment: When i turn off ads the game will load into the url that time only im getting the message "Rotate your device"

Comment: I want only it should be landscape when it show "rotate your device", i want auto rotation

Comment: But isn't that always? You keep changing your requirements.

Comment: Just check the url now http://deuceswildcards.site/wildcards.php?app=fun&Gtype=poker#/main

Comment: This case i don't want to the landscape because it will loads into portrait mode but if i turn off the ads it will be landscape because otherwise it will show that message.

Comment: I need auto rotation, the app should automatically detect weather the data in the url can be loaded in landscape or portrait

Comment: That's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this programmatically in Java. In your onCreate method, try this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

Or, you can do it through your Manifest file like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

To check the current screen orientation: do the following:

```
int orientation = MainActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; 
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {      
    //The orientation is in portrait so it will set it to landscape
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
}else {
     //The orientation is now landscape which is what you want.
}
```

Comment: I don't want to set landscape permanently. When the device show "Rotate your device" message then only i want to make it landscape mode.

Comment: I made changes to my answer. I think this is what you want. It checks the current orientation and then if it is portrait, it sets it to landscape. Hope this helps!

Comment: you might need to set the following within your Activity on your manifest as well, if you're handling all rotation changes: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"