# App force change orientation landscape to portrait when start purchase flow

Tags: android, android-studio

> when start purchase flow, app force changed orientation landscape to portrait.
> I've try to set orientation at runtime, but it doesn't work

Comment: This answers your question. [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268218/change-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-a-button#:~:text=Yes%2C%20you%20can%20set%20the,SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)%3B%20setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.  ]

Comment: I had tried already,not working...@Rajasekhar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```