# Failed to redraw views when device orientation change

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-custom-view, redraw

I have developed a three-pane layout where up to two panes are visible at a time. Only in landscape mode multiple views are supported. Each pane contains arrows to change the visibility state so the panes distribution change.

When the application opens in portrait mode, the views transition works correctly. The same happens when the application is opened in landscape mode. The problem arises when device is rotated and the control should change the distribution of the panels. when device is rotated the state transition fails and panes disappear or are not in the position where they should be.

Due to the requirements of the application the activity host handle the configuration changes itself (`android:configChanges="orientation|screensize"`) and I can not disable this behavior. When `onConfigurationChanged` method is invoked in the host activity the control is notified to execute the state transition. Depending on the current visibility state and the new orientation the control determines the new state and calls the method responsible for executing the transition (`configureWidth` method in the control's code). Below the code of the host activity and the control:

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    CategoriesListFragment.OnCategoriesListSizeControlListener,
    TasksListFragment.OnTasksListSizeControlListener,
    TaskDetailFragment.OnTaskDetailSizeControlListener, OnStateChangeListener {

    // Multipanel control that will contain the fragments associated with the 
    // category list, task list and task detail.
    private ThreePaneLayout mMultiPaneControl;

    // Fragments
    private CategoriesListFragment mCategoriesListFragment;
    private TasksListFragment mTasksListFragment;
    private TaskDetailFragment mTaskDetailFragment;

    private int mScreenOrientation;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the initial orientation of the device
        mScreenOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        mMultiPaneControl = (ThreePaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.multiPaneControl);

        mCategoriesListFragment = CategoriesListFragment.newInstance();
        mTasksListFragment      = TasksListFragment.newInstance();
        mTaskDetailFragment     = TaskDetailFragment.newInstance();

        // Add the state change observers of the ThreePaneLayout control.
        // The client fragments use the events of the OnstateChangeListener interface to 
        // update the arrows orientation that user can use to redimension the panels
        mMultiPaneControl.addStateObserver(mCategoriesListFragment);
        mMultiPaneControl.addStateObserver(mTasksListFragment);
        mMultiPaneControl.addStateObserver(mTaskDetailFragment);

        mMultiPaneControl.addStateObserver(this);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.categoriesList, mCategoriesListFragment, "tag");
        transaction.add(R.id.tasksList, mTasksListFragment);
        transaction.add(R.id.taskDetail, mTaskDetailFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        mScreenOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        // When device orientationcchange notify the ThreePaneLyout control associated with the activity 
        // to update the distribution of its panels in order to improve usability
        mMultiPaneControl.deviceOrientationHasChange();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCategoriesListSizeControlSelected() {

        if (mScreenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            VisibilityState visibilityState = mMultiPaneControl.getVisibityState();

            if (visibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE ) {
                mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.LEFT_VISIBLE);
            } else if ( visibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_VISIBLE) {
                mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE);
            }

        } else { // Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

            // The only possible state if this event is received while the device in 
            // portrait orientation is MIDDLE_VISIBLE
            mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTasksListSizeControlSelected(boolean leftControl) {

        VisibilityState visibilityState = mMultiPaneControl.getVisibityState();

        if (leftControl) {

            if ( mScreenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ) {

                if (visibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE ) {
                    mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE);
                } else if (visibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE ) {
                    mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE);
                } else if (visibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE ) {
                    mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE);
                }   

            } else { // Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

                // The only possible state if this event is received while the device in 
                // portrait orientation is LEFT_VISIBLE
                mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.LEFT_VISIBLE);
            }

        } else {

            if (mScreenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

                if (visibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE) {
                    mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE);
                } else if (visibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE) {
                    mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE);
                } else if (visibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
                    mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE);
                }   

            } else { // Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

                // The only possible state if this event is received while the device in 
                // portrait orientation is RIGHT_VISIBLE
                mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.RIGHT_VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetailTaskSizeControlSelected() {

        VisibilityState visibilityState = mMultiPaneControl.getVisibityState();

        if (mScreenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            if ( visibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
                mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.RIGHT_VISIBLE);
            } else if ( visibilityState == VisibilityState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
                mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE);
            }   

        } else { // Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

            // The only possible state if this event is received while the device in 
            // portrait orientation is MIDDLE_VISIBLE
            mMultiPaneControl.setVisibilityState(VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE); 
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBeginTransitionState(VisibilityState oldState,
            VisibilityState newState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewStateVisible(VisibilityState newState) { /**/ }
}
```

***ThreePaneLayout.java***

```
/**
 * <p>Control to display up to three panels with a maximum of two simultaneously visible.</p>
 */
public class ThreePaneLayout extends LinearLayout {

    /**
     * Time control takes for the state change animation
     */
    public static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 300;

    private boolean isScrollingViews;

    /**
     * Possible control visibility states. The states are exclusive, ie, if the control is 
     * in state {@ link LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE} implies that the right pane is not visible.
     */
    public enum VisibilityState {
        LEFT_VISIBLE,
        LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE, 
        MIDDLE_VISIBLE, 
        MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE,
        RIGHT_VISIBLE
    }

    /**
     * Interface to be implemented by clients that require to be notified
     * when the visibility state change.
     */
    public interface OnStateChangeListener {

        /**
         * Method invoked by the control just prior to the transition state of visibility   
         * 
         * @param oldState   Estado actual de visibilidad control
         * @param newState   Proximo estado de visibilidad del control
         */
        void onBeginTransitionState(VisibilityState oldState, VisibilityState newState);

        /**
         * Method invoked by the control when its visibility status has been updated
         * 
         * @param newState   New visibility state of the control panels
         */
        void onNewStateVisible(VisibilityState newState);

    }

    // Reference to the three panels of the control
    private View mLeftView;
    private View mMiddleView;
    private View mRightView;

    // Variables that store the minimum and maximum widths that can have different panels
    private int mMinPaneWidth = -1;
    private int mMaxPaneWidth;
    private int mFullScreenWidth;

    // Stores the current device orientation
    private int mScreenOrientation;

    // Reference to the current state of the panels
    private VisibilityState mVisibilityState;

    /**
     * Lista de observadores de cambio de estado del control
     */
    private List<OnStateChangeListener> mStateListeners;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private Context mContext;

    public ThreePaneLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        Log.i("Log", "Llamado el constructor del control");

        mContext = context;

        mScreenOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ThreePaneLayout);
        String initialState = a.getString(R.styleable.ThreePaneLayout_initialState);

        if ( initialState != null ) { 
            // The initial state has been defined in the XML

            if (initialState.equals("left_visible")) {
                mVisibilityState = VisibilityState.LEFT_VISIBLE;
            } else if (initialState.equals("left_and_middle_visible")) {
                mVisibilityState = VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE;
            } 

        } else { 
            // The initial state is not defined in the XML, set the default state

            mVisibilityState = VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        if ( getChildCount() != 3 ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ThreePaneLayout requires defining three daughters views in the XML");
        }

        // Get a reference to the views that make control
        mLeftView   = getChildAt(0);
        mMiddleView = getChildAt(1);
        mRightView  = getChildAt(2);

        configureWidth();
    }

    /**
     * Set the weights of each of the views of the layout container.
     * 
     * If the method takes no arguments recalculates the weights based on the current  visibility 
     * state of the control. If this method receive a parameter is used as visibility state from 
     * which will be held on recalculation
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    private void configureWidth(VisibilityState ... args) {

        LayoutParams leftPaneLayoutParams   = (LayoutParams) mLeftView.getLayoutParams();
        LayoutParams middlePaneLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) mMiddleView.getLayoutParams();
        LayoutParams rightPaneLayoutParams  = (LayoutParams) mRightView.getLayoutParams();

        VisibilityState visibilityState = args.length == 0 ? mVisibilityState : args[0];

        if (args.length > 0) {

            leftPaneLayoutParams.width   = 0;
            middlePaneLayoutParams.width = 0;
            rightPaneLayoutParams.width  = 0;
        }

        if ( visibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_VISIBLE ) {

            leftPaneLayoutParams.weight   = 1.0f; 
            middlePaneLayoutParams.weight = 0.0f; 
            rightPaneLayoutParams.weight  = 0.0f; 

        } else if ( visibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE ) {

            leftPaneLayoutParams.weight   = 0.35f;
            middlePaneLayoutParams.weight = 0.65f;
            rightPaneLayoutParams.weight  = 0.0f; 

        } else if ( visibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE ) {

            leftPaneLayoutParams.weight   = 0.0f; 
            middlePaneLayoutParams.weight = 1.0f;
            rightPaneLayoutParams.weight  = 0.0f;

        } else if ( visibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE ) {

            leftPaneLayoutParams.weight   = 0.0f;
            middlePaneLayoutParams.weight = 0.35f;
            rightPaneLayoutParams.weight  = 0.65f;

        } else if ( visibilityState == VisibilityState.RIGHT_VISIBLE ) {

            leftPaneLayoutParams.weight   = 0.0f;
            middlePaneLayoutParams.weight = 0.0f;
            rightPaneLayoutParams.weight  = 1.0f;
        }

        // Refresh the view and compute the size of the view in the screen. 
        requestLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Method that performs the visibility state transition control (redistribution of the panels)
     * 
     * @param newVisibilityState   New visibility state required.
     * @param resetDimensions      This parameter is optional and should be used only when you are performing a 
     *                             state transcion due to a change of device orientation so we can recalculated 
     *                             weights and widths of the panels.
     */
    public void setVisibilityState(VisibilityState newVisibilityState, boolean ... resetDimensions) {

        // Ignore the request if the control is being resized or if the requested state is equal to the current
        if ( isScrollingViews || newVisibilityState == mVisibilityState ) {
            return;
        }

        // If requested any state that contains more than one panel and device orientation is portrait, 
        // ignore the request (this control only supports multiple panels visible in landscape)
        if (mScreenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            if ( newVisibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE || 
                 newVisibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE ) {
                return;
            }
        }

        if (resetDimensions.length > 0 && resetDimensions[0] == true) {

            configureWidth(newVisibilityState);
            mMinPaneWidth = -1;
        }

        // Calculate the maximum and minimum widths of the control panel if the have not been defined
        if (mMinPaneWidth == -1) {

            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

            if ( mScreenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ) {

                mMinPaneWidth    = (int) (screenWidth * 0.35);
                mMaxPaneWidth    = screenWidth - mMinPaneWidth;
                mFullScreenWidth = screenWidth;

            } else { // Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

                mMinPaneWidth = mMaxPaneWidth = mFullScreenWidth = screenWidth;
            }

            resetWidget(mLeftView, mMinPaneWidth); 
            resetWidget(mMiddleView, mMaxPaneWidth);
            resetWidget(mRightView, mMaxPaneWidth);

            requestLayout();
        }

        isScrollingViews = true;
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                isScrollingViews = false;
            }
        }, ANIMATION_DURATION + 100);


        VisibilityState currentVisibilityState = mVisibilityState;

        // Notify control observers will produce a state transition 
        if ( mStateListeners != null ) {
            for ( OnStateChangeListener observer : mStateListeners ) {
                observer.onBeginTransitionState(currentVisibilityState, newVisibilityState);
            }
        }

        if (resetDimensions.length == 0) {
            // Perform the movement of the panels to match the new state required
            animateVisibilityStateTransition(currentVisibilityState, newVisibilityState);           
        }

        // Update the reference to the current state
        mVisibilityState = newVisibilityState;

        // Notify the new control state to the control's observers 
        if ( mStateListeners != null ) {
            for ( OnStateChangeListener observer : mStateListeners ) {
                observer.onNewStateVisible(mVisibilityState);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Moves on the x axis and resize the panels to suit new visibility state required.
     * 
     * @param currentVisibilityState    Current state control visibility
     * @param requiredVisibilityState   New visibility state required
     */
    private void animateVisibilityStateTransition(VisibilityState currentVisibilityState, 
            VisibilityState requiredVisibilityState) {

        switch (requiredVisibilityState) {

        case LEFT_VISIBLE:

            if (mScreenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

                if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE) {

                    ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "leftWidth", mMinPaneWidth, mFullScreenWidth)
                            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
                }

            } else { // Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

                if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE) {

                    translateView(mMaxPaneWidth, mLeftView, mMiddleView, mRightView);

                } else if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {

                    translateView(2 * mMaxPaneWidth, mLeftView, mMiddleView, mRightView);
                }
            } 

            break;

        case LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE:
            // Este estado solo es posible en orientacion panoramica

            if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE) {

                translateView(mMinPaneWidth, mLeftView, mMiddleView, mRightView);

                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "middleWidth", mFullScreenWidth, mMaxPaneWidth)
                        .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();

            } else if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE) {

                translateView(mMinPaneWidth, mLeftView, mMiddleView, mRightView);

                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "middleWidth", mMinPaneWidth, mMaxPaneWidth)
                        .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();

            } else if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_VISIBLE) {

                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "leftWidth", mFullScreenWidth, mMinPaneWidth)
                        .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
            }

            break;

        case MIDDLE_VISIBLE:

            if (mScreenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) { 

                if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE) {

                    translateView(-1 * mMinPaneWidth, mLeftView, mMiddleView, mRightView);

                    ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "middleWidth", mMaxPaneWidth, mFullScreenWidth)
                            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();

                } else if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE) {

                    ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "middleWidth", mMinPaneWidth, mFullScreenWidth)
                            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
                }

            } else { // Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

                if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_VISIBLE) {

                    translateView(-1 * mMaxPaneWidth, mLeftView, mMiddleView, mRightView);

                } else if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {

                    translateView(mMaxPaneWidth, mLeftView, mMiddleView, mRightView);
                }

            }

            break;

        case MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE:
            // Este estado solo es posible en orientacion panoramica

            if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE) {

                translateView(-1 * mMinPaneWidth, mLeftView, mMiddleView, mRightView);

                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "middleWidth", mMaxPaneWidth, mMinPaneWidth)
                        .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();

            } else if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE) {

                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "middleWidth", mFullScreenWidth, mMinPaneWidth)
                        .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();


            } else if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {

                translateView(mMinPaneWidth, mLeftView, mMiddleView, mRightView);

                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "rightWidth", mFullScreenWidth, mMaxPaneWidth)
                        .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
            }

            break;

        case RIGHT_VISIBLE:

            if (mScreenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) { 

                if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE) {

                    translateView(-1 * mMinPaneWidth, mLeftView, mMiddleView, mRightView);

                    ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "rightWidth", mMaxPaneWidth, mFullScreenWidth)
                            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
                }

            } else { // Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

                if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_VISIBLE) {

                    translateView(-2 * mMaxPaneWidth, mLeftView, mMiddleView, mRightView);

                } else if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE) {

                    translateView(-1 * mMaxPaneWidth, mLeftView, mMiddleView, mRightView);
                }
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    public VisibilityState getVisibityState() {
        return mVisibilityState;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setLeftWidth(int value) {
        mLeftView.getLayoutParams().width = value;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setMiddleWidth(int value) {
        mMiddleView.getLayoutParams().width = value;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setRightWidth(int value) {
        mRightView.getLayoutParams().width = value;
        requestLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Moves in the X axis the views received as parameter.
     *   
     * @param deltaX   Number of pixels that are shifted in the x-axis views
     * @param views    Views on which it will move
     */
    private void translateView(int deltaX, View... views) {

        for (final View view : views) {

            view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);

            view.animate().translationXBy(deltaX).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION)
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the properties of length and weight on the layout of the view passed as parameter 
     * 
     * @param view    Vista on which perform the update of the properties
     * @param width   New width
     */
    private void resetWidget(View view, int width) {

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.width = width;
        p.weight = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the component passed as a parameter to the list of control observers. The observers are notified
     * every time the control change the panels distribution. Observers also receive a notification just before 
     * starting the transition state by the control.
     * 
     * @param observer   component that implements the {@ link OnStateChangeListener} interface
     *                   to recieve notifications when the visibility control state change
     */
    public void addStateObserver(OnStateChangeListener observer) {

        if ( mStateListeners == null ) {
            mStateListeners = new ArrayList<OnStateChangeListener>();
        }

        mStateListeners.add(observer);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the component passed as parameter from the list of observers of 
     * state change. Observers are added to the list through the method {@ link # addStateObserver}
     * 
     * @param observer   component that implements the {@ link OnStateChangeListener} interface
     *                   to recieve notifications when the visibility control state change
     */
    public void deleteStatetObserver(OnStateChangeListener observer) {

        if ( mStateListeners == null ) return;

        mStateListeners.remove(observer);
    }


    /**
     * Method invoked by the host activity when the orientation of the device has changed. Based on the 
     * new orientation the control redistributes panels to match the new orientation and improve usability
     */
    public void deviceOrientationHasChange() 
    {
        int newScreenOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        VisibilityState currentVisibilityState = getVisibityState();
        VisibilityState newVisibilityState = null;

        if (newScreenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            // When orientation chamge to landscape the only possible states in the previous orientation 
            // (portrait) can only be those where not coexist multiple views (eg LEFT_VISIBLE, 
            // MIDDLE_VISIBLE, RIGHT_VISIBLE)

            if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_VISIBLE) {
                newVisibilityState = VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE;
            } else if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE) {
                newVisibilityState = VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE;
            } else if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
                newVisibilityState = VisibilityState.RIGHT_VISIBLE;
            }

        } else { // Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

            if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_VISIBLE) {
                newVisibilityState = VisibilityState.LEFT_VISIBLE;
            } else if ( currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.LEFT_AND_MIDDLE_VISIBLE || 
                        currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE ) {
                newVisibilityState = VisibilityState.MIDDLE_VISIBLE;
            } else if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.MIDDLE_AND_RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
                newVisibilityState = VisibilityState.RIGHT_VISIBLE;
            } else if (currentVisibilityState == VisibilityState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
                newVisibilityState = VisibilityState.RIGHT_VISIBLE;
            }
        }

        mScreenOrientation = newScreenOrientation;

        mMinPaneWidth = -1;
        configureWidth(newVisibilityState);

        mVisibilityState = newVisibilityState;
    }

    public View getLeftView() {
        return mLeftView;
    }

    public View getMiddleView() {
        return mMiddleView;
    }

    public View getRightView() {
        return mRightView;
    }

}
```

For example when the device is in landscape and the visibility state is MIDDLE AND RIGHT (see Figure 1) when you rotate the device to portrait the state change fails (see Figure 2).

[image]

***Figure 1***

[image]

***Figure 2***

For a more detailed analysis of the application, I posted on github a sample application that uses the control and is available for download at the following link: https://github.com/dfpalomar/ThreePaneLayout

I tried to force the redraw of the views using the methods `requestLayout`, `invalidate` and `forceLayout` from controls's configureWidth method but without the desired results.

Any suggestions on how I could solve the problem is welcome :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change screen orientation in Android without reloading the activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873755/change-screen-orientation-in-android-without-reloading-the-activity)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that link is not related to my problem. As I mentioned above I specified that activity should not be recreated when device orientation change because the operations it have to do are very costly. I have no problem with the logic responsible for maintaining the activity state when I rotate the device, my problem concerns when I do the calculations to repaint the panes these are in locations where they should not be or simply disappear I do not know what I'm doing wrong to redraw the views.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic functionality to keep session when changing screen rotation, you need to do this manually yourself since the activity is being reloaded. You can read the details here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

There are also many similar questions here on StackOverflow, so please also try searching for this to get a suitable answer.

Comment: I have implemented the functionality to maintain the activity session. My problem is related to the calculations I do to redraw and reposition the control panes.