# How can I keep the input text in webview after orientation change in Android

Tags: android, webview, rotation, screen-orientation, orientation-changes

I have a Android App using simple Webview. There are a number of input areas and textarea on the web. Currently when user change orientation of the mobile device, all the inputs got swiped out and refreshed. How can I retain all those inputs after orientation change?

I do not wish to limit users to have only portrait or landscape mode when using the app.

I have read these questions but seems they do not work. They are only related to preventing reload of activity.

[Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)
[Change screen orientation in Android without reloading the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873755/change-screen-orientation-in-android-without-reloading-the-activity)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your activity

```
@Override

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        System.out.println("this's landscape");

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        System.out.println("this's portrait");
    }
}
```

in your manifest(inside your activity tag)

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```