# Realoding when screen orientation changed

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a `WebView` application, when i change the screen orientation of application it reloads itself.

I am using

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp34"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name0"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp34.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp34.AboutUs"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about_us" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I do not want it to reload again. I want that it continues showing normally when I change screen orientation.

Comment: In Android Activity lifecycle, it is destroyed and recreating again after orientation changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329318/android-how-to-not-destroy-the-activity-when-i-rotate-the-device

Comment: According to your link before i was using only android:configChanges="orientation" and tehre was that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on our main activity java
and removed

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Also added

```
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
```

to manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: it wont let the screen orientation change. that is not what we want. we want to stop recreating the activity.

Comment: I want to use in both portrait or landscape

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:configChanges=”orientation|screenSize|uiMode"`
or in case you don't want to react to changes in screen orientation, you should add `android:screenOrientation=”portrait”`

Comment: android:configChanges=”orientation|screenSize|uiMode" doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Add "`keyboardhidden`" to `android:configchanges` and you try delete "**screensize**"

Answer (score 0):

Set your screen orientation. This problem mainly due to the screen orientations... 
Update your manifest file as

```
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: i need to use on both orientation