# Mediaplayer starts playing music again when user slides in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-mediaplayer

I have simple imageview app that plays music in background. However, my problem is when user turns device sidewards in other words landscape mode.. the first music (say for a), starts to play again and the music that was playing first also plays along with it. I know I have some problem with media player but I don't know where exactly it is located in my code...How to stop this issue....

Maainactivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer oursong;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ImageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
         oursong.seekTo(0);
         oursong.start();

         viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
         adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
         viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


         viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(MyViewPagerListener);
    }



    private int pos = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

           if(oursong != null){
               pos = oursong.getCurrentPosition();
               oursong.release();
               oursong = null;
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
          super.onResume();

         /*
          * This is the important part, basically since your releasing the song
          * in onPause() you are getting rid of its reference, in this case check
          * if your song is null then if it is re-create it, else you can reuse the
          * the original, but i suspect that calling release() in onPause() allows the
          * song to get cleaned up by Java's Garbage Collector.
          */
         oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
         oursong.seekTo(pos); // You will probably want to save an int to restore here
         oursong.start();
    }
   /*
    * May want to add two methods here: onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outstate) &
    * onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) to maintain playback position
    * in onResume instead of just restarting the song.
    */

   private final OnPageChangeListener MyViewPagerListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
              if (pos == adapter.getCount() - 1){
                 // adding null checks for safety
                 if(oursong != null){
                    oursong.pause();
                 }

               } else if (!oursong.isPlaying()){ 

                // adding null check for safety
                if(oursong != null){
                    oursong.start();
                }
              }         
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you rotate the phone and you switch from portrait to landscape, the activity is destroyed and recreated, meaning that onCreate() is called again.

Adding this line to the manifest you tell android not to destroy your activity in such situations.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

More info [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329318/android-how-to-not-destroy-the-activity-when-i-rotate-the-device)