# Android WebView loads startpage when turning smartphone

Tags: java, android, webview, reload

I got this code (relevant part only):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private int whichPage = 0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(this.getString(whichPage == 0 ? R.string.vPlan : R.string.tPlan));
    }
}
```

In the OptionsMenu the user can change the page...
Now my problem is that each time the user turns his/her phone it will load R.string.vPlan even if it was set to tPlan (and whichPage contained 1).

Is there a way to stop the app from jumping to vPlan or even stop it from loading a page at all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you turn the smartphone, the activity is being re-created and the variables are being re-initialized. So every time you rotate, the `whichPage` value is being set to `0`. You have two options:

1- You can use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` to save the activity state (the required variables which you want to keep track of even when user rotates). Checkout [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-on-android) and [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

2- [Stop the activity from being recreated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329318/android-how-to-not-destroy-the-activity-when-i-rotate-the-device) on rotating the device. However [Google Engineers suggest against](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335665/avoid-reloading-activity-with-asynctask-on-orientation-change-in-android/5336057#5336057) this way.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @user5055454 Sorry, didn't understand you.

Answer (score 0):

try this if it helps

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;
private int whichPage = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

if (savedInstanceState == null){

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(this.getString(whichPage == 0 ? R.string.vPlan : R.string.tPlan));
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```

}