# OnCreateView Fragment called twice

Tags: android, fragment

i have this problem the method OnCreateView of my Fragment is called twice when the user rotates the device and it changes all the values in the second call, here is the code of this fragment, i just create this fragment if the saveInstanceState of previous fragment is null.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_datos_reborn, container, false);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    //declaracion de fragment de resultados

    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("resultados_fragment")==null){
        resultadosFragment=new ResultadosFragment();
    }
    view.findViewById( R.id.aceptarDatos).setOnClickListener(this);
    //Asignaciones de RadioGroup del tipo de regresión
        mRGTipoDeRegresion=(RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.rGTipoDeRegresion);

        rBTipoLineal=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rBLineal);
        rBTipoLineal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tipoDeRegresion="lineal";
            }
        });
        rBTipoPotencial=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rBPotecial);
        rBTipoPotencial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tipoDeRegresion="potencial";
            }
        });
    //Se pregunta si es tablet
    esTablet=getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.es_tablet);

    //obtener recycler
    recycler = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerDatos);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mBundle=this.getArguments();


    //        if (savedInstanceState==null){
    if (savedInstanceState==null){
        ejecutadoDesdePul=mBundle.getInt("ejecutado_desde_pulsasion");
    }else {
        ejecutadoDesdePul=0;
    }


    //        if (ejecutadoDesdePul==1){
    if (savedInstanceState==null){
        elementoFuePulsado=mBundle.getBoolean("elemento_pulsado");
        botonAceptarFuePulsado=mBundle.getBoolean("botonAceptarPulsado");
    }else {
        elementoFuePulsado=false;
        botonAceptarFuePulsado=false;
    }
    if(elementoFuePulsado==true){
        numeroDeVariables=0;
        variablesX=Funciones.convertirADoubleArrayComplejo(mBundle.getDoubleArray("valoresX"));
        variablesY=Funciones.convertirADoubleArrayComplejo(mBundle.getDoubleArray("valoresY"));
        elementoFuePulsado=false;
    }else if(botonAceptarFuePulsado==true) {
        numeroDeVariables=mBundle.getInt("numero_de_variables");
        botonAceptarFuePulsado=false;
        if (savedInstanceState==null){
            if (giroPantalla!=true) {
                variablesX = new Double[numeroDeVariables];
                variablesY = new Double[numeroDeVariables];
                giroPantalla=false;
            }
        }
    }
    tipoDeRegresion=mBundle.getString("tipo_de_regresion","");

    etiquetaX=mBundle.getString("nombre_x");
    etiquetaY=mBundle.getString("nombre_y");



    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
        poblarLista();
    }


    if (savedInstanceState==null){
        if (tipoDeRegresion.equals("lineal")){
            mRGTipoDeRegresion.check(R.id.rBLineal);
            Funciones.hacerToastCorto(getActivity(),"Entra");
        }else if (tipoDeRegresion.equals("potencial")){
            mRGTipoDeRegresion.check(R.id.rBPotecial);
            Funciones.hacerToastCorto(getActivity(),"Entra");
        }
        pasarAResultados();
    }
    if (ejecutadoDesdePul>=1){
        ejecutadoDesdePul++;
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: How do you actually know that your fragment's `onCreateView` is called twice? And can you post the full code for fragment, please?

Comment: @IulianPopescu I know it because i debuged my app and i have used breakpoints.

Comment: And what is the name of this fragment?

Comment: I add the code here https://paste.ofcode.org/XUXJn98nDXmVvQYnUGQDRF

Comment: Can you share the code where you add this fragment?

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/jhNQKDmeacZTwXfBhkCmt3 @IulianPopescu Here is the fragment where the DatosFragmentReborn is created.

Answer (score 1):

For API 12 and below: add

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

For API 13 or above: add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

to your activity, in which there is your fragment, in your Manifest

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329318/android-how-to-not-destroy-the-activity-when-i-rotate-the-device)

Comment: Thanks but when i add this the content layout is the same of portrait and landscape and i dont want this.

Comment: @LEAJIM_454 In this way if you rotate the screen, the activity (with the fragment )doesn't destroy, where is the problem? i didn't understand you in this comment