# How to get dialog that is attached with DialogFragment? [ANDROID]

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

In my app i am using ***DialogFragment*** to show a dialog for some seconds, now when i change my device's screen orientation, app crashes because the context i am using in my Dialog fragment goes null.
After searching i found that in my activity's ***onDestroy()*** method i should dismiss that dialog if it is already showing so that my app doesn't crash.
Now i need to get that dialog that is showing how i can get it? so that i can implement a check on it
Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329318/android-how-to-not-destroy-the-activity-when-i-rotate-the-device

Comment: You can handle it by overriding  `onConfigurationChanged` https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange .This will avoid the activity to get restarted again and hence context will not become null.

Comment: @vikashkumarpandey thats for the link it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add in your menifest file

```
"android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

in the actvity tag like below :

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.HistoryDefectDetail"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```